# pgadmin 4 (or db visualiser) entity relation diagram

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, dbvisualizer, entity-relationship

How do you make an entity relation diagram using pgAdmin v4 or DB Visualizer or any other open source tool?

**PG Admin**
There are lots of explainers for pgadmin III but they suggest that there should be a tab called 'graphical query builder under the tools/query menu. There isnt. It has since been explained that this feature no longer exists in pgadmin.

**Objective**
I have 70 tables in my schema and I'm trying to find instructions for how to generate a graphical representation of the relations between them.

Does anyone know where to find instructions for how to do this with an open source tool (written in clear english)?

**DB Visualizer**
I've separately downloaded DB Visualiser on my mac, but I  cant find instructions for how to locate and connect my database, but the table values don't make sense to me. I get a successful connection message showing and then I can see the name of the db (that I enter in the wizard) on the connections tab, but all of the menus underneath that are gibberish - none of them show my schema.

Does anyone know how to generate an entity relation diagram from Postgres on a mac?

Comment: "*How do you make an entity relation diagram using pgAdmin v4?*" - you don't. It doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: pgAdmin 3 has a graphical query builder.

Comment: is there an equivalent in pg admin 4? I cant find it if there is. I cant figure out how to connect my db to Db Visualizer. I don't care what tool (even if i have to pay for it) - I just cant find a way to build this

Comment: @Jakob - I've downloaded v3. but how do i get the Graphical Query Builder to build an entity relation diagram of all the tables in my schema. I cant find a way to click on the schema in the right hand column and then I'm trying to find a button to press to make it build the diagram.

Comment: * left hand column

Comment: Start by download DbVisualizer and then when it is running open Tools->Connection Wizard to setup the PostgreSQL connection. Now goto the Databases tab and expand the objects tree down to the Tables node, double-click it and to the right click the References tab to show the primary/foreign key graph. Read more in: http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG95/Viewing+Table+Relationships

Comment: @roger - thanks but there is no 'References' tab.

Comment: I can see that I get more options when i trial visualiser pro - but I still cant get a representation of entity relationships in a graph. The link you gave has instructions that don't match the options in the menus. Options to use imported/exported keys aren't in any menu. The foreign key is named in the graph produced as "serial id". There are no lines connecting tables in the graph generated. Is there more instructions somewhere else? Maybe the ones you found are out of date

Comment: i just get a graph showing independent boxes. I'm trying to depict them with lines showing the relationship. none of the 4 ways of representing these relationships work (e.g. organic) to produce lines connecting boxes based of reference id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found:   gem "rails-erd"
Which produced the diagram in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read elsewhere, at some point pgAdmin 3 removed its "Graphical Query Builder", but now in pgAdmin 4 there is an "ERB For Database" option when right clicking on a database:
[image]